# How to write tweet IDs to a CSV file as strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a column which contains a list of tweet IDs. A tweet ID could get as long as this '475685437424427008'. When I write this to a CSV file using the data.to_csv() method they get written as float. How do I retain the numbers as string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after writing a list of strings (long int converted to string) to a csv file using dataframe, while reading the same file pandas reads the column as int 64. While reading a csv file into dataframe we can specify the format for particular column.

sample.csv file contains:

```
45646879879779
54121798454644
79841321321549
44654646449879
```

I'm running:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', converters={'ID': str})
```

Where:

- sample.csv is the file which has the column 'ID'
- 'ID' column has the long int values.

Answer (score 1):

The `dtype` is probably a float but displayed as an integer, change the type:

```
df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(str)
```

You can confirm if this worked or not, using `df.dtypes`

It should display:

```
In [5]:
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)
df.dtypes
Out[5]:
a    object
dtype: object
```

should to the trick when you call `to_csv`